# antlr3 NOT rule

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

```
negExpression   :   (NOT^)* primitiveElement    ;
```

Is the rule I have. I now have this code:

```
!!(1==1)
```

I expected I would end up with this tree:

```
NOT
 |
NOT
 |
 ==
/  \
1  1
```

However, in Antlr3, it seems the tree ends up like

```
  NOT
 /   \
NOT  ==
    /  \
    1  1
```

IE. I end up with the second NOT having no children, instead the child node it should have, has become its sibling node.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And as I wrote the question, it came to me that my rule was perhaps wrong.
And indeed, this one does exactly what I expected.

```
negExpression : NOT^ negExpression | primitiveElement^;
```